# ¿Cuántas redes y computadores puedo tener en cada clase (A, B y C principalmente) de dirección IP?

Tags: redes, ip

Estoy estudiando redes y me ha surgido una duda con respecto al direccionamiento IP.

Las direcciones IP son de clase A, B y C principalmente.

- La A indica que se tienen 8 bits para red y 24 bits para host, eso quiere decir que tengo 256 posibles redes y 16 millones de computadoras para cada red, no?
- La B indica que se tienen 16 bits para red y 16 para host, eso quiere decir 65.000 redes y 65.000 computadores en cada red?

Por favor, que alguien me explique en qué me estoy equivocando...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como se explica en la página web de la [Comisión Interamericana de Comunicaciones](https://www.oas.org/en/citel/infocitel/2009/junio/protocolo2_e.asp), esos números no son válidos porque los primeros bits del identificador de red se usan para identificar la clase de dirección que se está utilizando.

Entonces, realmente no estás utilizando todos los bits de red para identificar la red en sí:

[image: imagen con clases de red y bits usados en cada caso]
(fuente: [info@citel](https://www.oas.org/en/citel/infocitel/2009/junio/protocolo2_e.asp))

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha resuelto bastante bien la duda. Un saludo!

Comment: Las respuestas que son sólo un enlace se consideran de baja calidad porque si el enlace cambia o se rompe, la respuesta deja de tener sentido. Por favor, edita tu publicación para incluir las partes claves de la página enlazada en la propia respuesta (manteniendo el enlace como referencia).